# Compiler check Annotation of Class

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible that the compiler checks if an `Annotation` is defined on a `Class` when I pass the `Class` as method parameter?

I want to use an `Annotation` like an marker `Interface`. Instead of using the interface `MarkerInterface`:

```
void method(Class<? extends MarkerInerface>);
```

I'd like the compiler to check for an `Annotation`. e.g. `MyAnnotation`:

```
void method(Class<? annotates MyAnnotation>);
```

Is there any way to do something?

Edit: The following code should lead to an compiler error:

```
method(Object.class); // Error since Object doesn't have MyAnnotation defined
method(MyClass.class); // fine.

@MyAnnotation
public class MyClass {...}
```

Comment: Can you make your question more concrete, such as by showing conforming client code that the compiler should approve, and showing non-conforming client code for which the compiler should issue a warning?

Comment: done. hope it's clear now. btw. I'm more thinking about an compiler error than of a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) does what you want.  The syntax is `Class<? extends @MyAnnotation Object>` rather than `Class<? annotates MyAnnotation>` as you wrote.

Here is a test case:

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.interning.qual.Interned;

public class ClassWithAnnotationTest {

  @Interned
  public class MyClass {}

  void method(Class<? extends @Interned Object> arg) {}

  void client() {
    method(Object.class);   // Error, Object isn't annotated by @Interned.
    method(MyClass.class);  // Fine.
  }
}
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
$ch/bin/javac -g ClassWithAnnotationTest.java -processor interning
ClassWithAnnotationTest.java:11: error: [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
    method(Object.class);   // Error, Object isn't annotated by @Interned.
                 ^
  found   : @Interned Class<Object>
  required: @Interned Class<? extends @Interned Object>
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, but first prepare your list of annotations to 
add to the scanner.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_DEFALT_FILTER>);

scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(<TYPE_YOUR_ANNOTATION_HERE>.class));

for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(<TYPE_YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE_HERE>))
    System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
```

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't fit my needs.